# Error in uploading apk in debug mode on google play store

Tags: android, debugging, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have implemented in app purchase in my application and for that i have to make app live on play store to check the purchase flow and also i have to trace that in my logcat in debug mode. So for that i am trying to signed apk in debug mode and upload to play store but play store is not allowing me to upload the apk in debug mode. My main purpose is to trace the flow of in app purchase in logcat. Does any know how can i achieve it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple answer, you can never upload the apk with different signature on playstore.

Comment: For testing the In App Purchases, did you try the [purchase sandboxing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)?

Comment: i know the sandboxing testing but want to trace it in logcat for the real product in play store - @MohammedAtif

Comment: I dont get your point. You can have the log cat even in the release version. Only put proper log messages for filtering.